# Why does my lubuntu 18.04 display tear when there's a lot of movement on a window?

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, display

I have recently installed Lubuntu and everything works fine except there's this problem of my screen breaking when there's a lot of movement on the screen. It happens a lot when I'm watching a video. I'm attaching a link to an example below. Also, the tearing happens at the same position always.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/adm9s.jpg

Thanks

Comment: What's that hopping window? Did _you_ move it or does it move on itself?

Comment: I was scrolling it to show the effect take place. It only happens when there's movement

Comment: You mean the Z shaped lower border of the black part? I'd guess that's quite normal when moving windows that quick.

Comment: I know it's not normal because it works fine in Windows. When I'm watching a movie for example, it occurs alot and is a bit disturbing

Comment: Shearing happens.  Vsync is a thing you can tweak for some video cards on the linux side of the house.  If you juggle a video window, it's going to happen.  I'm running an underpowered intel onboard video chipset, and I don't get shearing as long as I don't have a great many tabs open.  Not a bug or issue.  Usage forcing a behavior resulting in complaint.

Comment: Is there a fix to it?

Comment: Get a card that supports tweaking vsync (mid-range AMD and Nvidia both support tweaking with binary blobs) or reduce overall memory/processor/video card load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by installing compton:

```
sudo apt install compton
```

And adding this code to run every time the session starts:

```
compton --backend glx --vsync opengl
```

Comment: @shahlin_lbrahim can you exaplin it a little bit more? What does Compton do? Why does the code, you mention do? It will be helpful for the user who is having this issue. I have the same issue in Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: @shahlin-lbrahim Update: After installing it, and using the command u mentioned. After a day of testing,  it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Prabeshbhattarai Hey, not sure why it didn't work for you but unfortunately I no longer use Lubuntu or faced the issue ever since, so I can't provide enough information. Hopefully your answer works for others!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with **Ubuntu 19.10**, and the above-accepted answer didn't work for me. After my investigation, I found [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Tearing) **ArchWiki** page where this issue is addressed and solved. If you have are on Ubuntu distro, you have to read [this](https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/screen-tearing-on-intel-graphics.html).

TLDR; do this if you don't want to read the link I have mention and directly solve the problem:

```
    sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
    sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

And add this lines:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

And exit the file. You might have to reboot.